# Duplicates: why not be able to choose more than one?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, possible-duplicates

When you opt to close a question due to its being a duplicate, the program automatically churns up examples and you have to choose one.

Often, more than one applies, yet there is only one choice possible.

That's too bad.

I am talking about a new "feature".

Comment: This seems to be the only question on ELL Meta tagged "choices" or "duplicate". Can you explain how those tags are supposed to be used? They have no usage guidance. (Also, why do we need "duplicate" when "possible-duplicates" already exists?)

Comment: *If enough close voters agree that the question is a duplicate, or if the asker agrees, or if a sufficiently privileged user votes to close*, **then the question will be [closed as a duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-or-duplicate-question)**. After that point, the question remains on the site, but new answers can only be added on the target question. Also, pending votes to close the target question as a duplicate of the now-closed question will be invalidated, preventing a duplicate "circle".*

Comment: @lambie You cannot close a question as a duplicate of two or more questions. You must pick one question. BUT if you have the gold badge you can edit the notice and make a list of questions that you consider the new question is a duplicate of.

Comment: Put in the search box the following string **"present perfect" duplicate:yes** and you'll get every question asking about the present perfect that has been closed as a duplicate [RESULTS](https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22present+perfect%22+duplicate%3Ayes)

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes, but **once again** how do you LIST THOSE in a comment like you did?? I put that in my search box, I got all the duplicates but not how to cut-and-paste them like you did.

Comment: I showed you how to embed the links in the comment I posted [Like this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/343403/i-have-had-never-eaten-sushi-before#comment661929_343403). To embed it's: [ **Question Title** ] no space ( **URL** ) Don't leave any spaces.

Comment: From Meta Stack Exchange: [Use hyperlink in comment?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121422/use-hyperlink-in-comment#comment321705_121422) Read the comment and the answer below.

Comment: there is nothing that prevents  you from posting two  or more links in a comment. I manage to post up to four links because I know where to shorten the URLS. You should fit three question links though.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Once more: When I vote for closing using duplicate, a BUNCH of them come up and I do not know how to choose them to put in a comment. Could you please try and understand what I am saying? Thanks. I know how to post internet links in comments. I don't know how to COPY or GET them from the Duplicates page IN ORDER to put them in a comment Is that clear??

Comment: The list of "duplicates" I found for myself. But if that's not your thing then visit the actual posts in the BUNCH and then post the links, one at a time (as I did) in the comment. You cannot post multiple links at the same time, IF that is what you are asking about.

Comment: @Mari-LouA My question here was about that. There should be **a way** to easily select the list that appears when hitting Duplicate. I think I explained it in my question; we should have a **new feature** that allows copying the links under Duplicate easily.

Comment: Not everything that comes up in a duplicate list is relevant.As users who decide closing someone's new question, we should make sure the older Q has answers to the new question. Ask Glorfindel, he is often in Meta Stack Exchange, if he thinks it's a viable request.

Comment: What shown as possible duplicates is not a list from which people who close to vote **must** choose the duplicate question. It is just a list programmatically populated with what could be a possible duplicate, but as @Mari-LouA said, it could also contain irrelevant questions. All the times I closed a question as duplicate, I already knew what the duplicated question was; the list eventually avoided me to paste the question link because the duplicated question was already listed in the first items of that list.

Comment: As for being able to select more than a question as duplicate when voting to close a question, that is not necessary in most of the cases: The question is closed as duplicate because it duplicates a single question already asked, not because there are two or more questions that can be considered duplicates. In the rare cases there is the need to point out there are more questions that could be helpful to people who are looking for an answer to the closed question, moderators and users with the gold badge for one of the used tags can add more question links that are shown on the top banner.

Comment: @apaderno My quesiton here is not about selecting more than one question as a duplicate. It's about signalling more than one answer in the list of duplicate answers that are **good answers.**

Comment: I guess you wrote *answer* where you mean *question*. There is not a way to signal questions as *good questions* in the list of duplicate questions. The list is automatically populated basing on which questions have been chosen as duplicates, the tags the closed question used, and other details. The only way to show *good [duplicate] questions* is to select them as duplicates.

Comment: @apaderno I explained myself many times above.

Comment: @Lambie I have read the comments but, still, selecting more questions when closing a question as duplicate has not the effect of showing *good questions*. Stack Exchange has already decided that only moderators and gold tag-badge holders can edit the duplicate question shown on the banner and even add further links to duplicate questions.

Comment: @apaderno I explained myself many times and you still do not get what I was saying. I don't see how I could have been clearer. **It is not about closing a question as duplicate!** It's about **choosing** more than one of the suggestions in the duplicates list so more than one can be shown under:  Does this answer your question?

Comment: @Lambie *Stack Exchange has already decided that only moderators and gold tag-badge holders can edit the duplicate question shown on the banner and even add further links to duplicate questions.* That covers that too.

Comment: Then, the question does not even say *links to questions to show in "Does this answer your question?"* which, in case you missed it, it is a comment created for the user who first votes to close a question as duplicate of an existing question. You should not wonder people also said that you can manually add a new comment, if you need to point out there are other questions that could be considered duplicates.

Comment: Actually, the question does not even says what feature is requesting. It says *Often, more than one applies, yet there is only one choice possible.* which could be taken as *Often, more than one applies, yet there is only one choice possible. Users should be able to choose more questions that are then shown in the "closed question" banner.* or *Often, more than one applies, yet there is only one choice possible. The first user who votes to close as duplicate should be able to choose more than a question as duplicates which are then shown in the "Does this answer your question?" comment.*

Answer (score 7):

You can always add other possible duplicates in a comment. If another user votes to close as another duplicate, and the question is eventually closed as a duplicate, both links will appear. And finally, [Gold tag-badge holders and moderators can now edit duplicate links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291824/295232) - if it's really helpful to have an additional duplicate (or the current one is wrong), you can ping or flag a moderator to help out.

Comment: I am not talking about in a comment. I mean signal the ones that are relevant so those reading Duplicate can see it straight away.